# why it has different behavior in different ide online or not

Tags: c++, ide, online-compilation

Assuming this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int letters_counted_in_text( std::string const&text ) {
  int count = 0;
  string abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";

  for( unsigned i=0; i<text.length(); ++i )
    for( unsigned j=0; j<abc.length(); ++j )
      if( text.at( i )==abc.at( j ) )
      {
        count++;
        j=abc.length();
      }
  return count;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string test = "Hola, cómo estás";
    cout << letters_counted_in_text(test);

    return 0;
}
```

---

why it has different behavior in `codechef`:

**OutPut:**

```
13
```

https://www.codechef.com/ide

But in `ideone` is:

**OutPut:**

```
15
```

https://ideone.com/jzbxA1

in `cpp.sh` **OutPut:** is 15

---

To what can this behavior be? I'm sorry for my bad english I hope you can understand what I say?

Comment: Several of the characters you use are not represented in ASCII so different extensions of ASCII (or other encodings) could produce different results. Place a breakpoint on count++ and see what triggers it.

Comment: Come to think of it, here's what happens if I dump your strings to UTF-8 and then read it back as ASCII: "Hola, cÃ³mo estÃ¡s" 15 characters.

Comment: @user4581301 It makes sense. But because codechef it is not the same, can it be by some compiler configuration? thanks for your time

Comment: I think you need to `string test = u8"Hola, cómo estás";`, but I unfortunately don't know how to turn a UTF-8 string literal into a `wstring` to do the compare without converting to a stream and back.

Comment: I was wrong. Easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a character encoding problem. In your source code several characters used are not members of ASCII. This leave you open to different encodings and different interpretations of extended ASCII.

For example, saving your source as UTF-8 and then opening with an editor that only reads raw ASCII, the strings come out

```
string abc = "abcdefghijklmnÃ±opqrstuvwxyzÃ¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºABCDEFGHIJKLMNÃ‘OPQRSTUVWXYZÃÃ‰ÃÃ“Ãš";
```

and

```
string test = "Hola, cÃ³mo estÃ¡s";
```

That puts 15 characters in `test` that are also in `abc` because some of the characters took up more than one byte. Using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` should help with this, but you also need to use widechar string literals

```
wstring abc = L"abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚ";
```

and

```
wstring test = L"Hola, cómo estás";
```

and of course

```
int letters_counted_in_text(std::wstring const&text)
```

because we need to pass `wstring` in to the function.

Here it is on ideone: http://ideone.com/fAVPKt

Now we're left with the question, "Why did this work on CodeChef?"

Comment: Thank you for your time, I upvote and I will mark as accepted, and if there is another one that solves the CodeChef mystery I will remove it.

Comment: I test your code in codechef and I get this -> `error: converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character` Maybe it helps to know why. But no error in ideone.

Comment: @AngelAngel Got that myself. They are doing something weird with UTF-8. I don't know what, but I don't think it's kosher.